# Console application not torn down by an unhandled task exception

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to figure out why my console app is not torn down by an unhandled task exception. All I do is create a task where I immediately throw an exception. Finally I force GC. In the first example I have a handler for the `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` event and I can see the exception get handled.

```
 static async Task ThrowsException()
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Throwing!");
     throw new Exception("Test exception");
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += TaskScheduler_UnobservedTaskException;
    ThrowsException();
    Console.WriteLine("Collecting garbage.");
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    Console.WriteLine("Done collecting garbage.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static void TaskScheduler_UnobservedTaskException(object sender,
   UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unobserved task exception occured in finalizer.");
    Console.WriteLine(e.Exception.InnerException.Message);
}
```

Output:

```
Throwing!
Collecting garbage.
Unobserved task exception occured in finalizer.
Test exception
Done collecting garbage.
```

But if I comment out the line `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += TaskScheduler_UnobservedTaskException` the program still runs to completion. In this case the output is:

```
Throwing!
Collecting garbage.
Done collecting garbage.
```

Why doesn't the application crash in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not crashing the program from a unobserved task exception was a change that was made for .NET 4.5, see the [remarks section of the MSDN for the event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception(v=vs.110).aspx). If you want your program to have the pre .NET 4.5 behavior and cause it to crash you need to put in your app.config

```
<configuration> 
   <runtime> 
      <ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions enabled="true"/> 
   </runtime> 
</configuration>
```

This will bring back the old behavior.

Answer (score 0):

ThrowsException is an async method and therefore unless you'll wait on this method, the exception will be swallowed.
I assume that you need to call this method like this:

```
ThrowsException.Wait();
```

Or even catch the exception:

```
try
{
    ThrowsException().Wait();
}
catch (AggregateException e)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Also, reading the following will help you understand why it didn't crash your application: [TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true).